# Javascript form inputs created dynamically from json and need to map object to proper field from another object and save

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, object

I am going to do the best I can explaining what I am trying to do here. Its a bit complex(for me at least)
I currently have an object that I loop through and populate an html form with inputs dynamically. This code places the object values in the inputs and allows me to edit/save them back to the object.
What I need to do however, is actually map the object fields to a set of fields that are defined in another object. The reason for this is that the original Object sometimes is missing data and I would like to add it from my form.
For example: My object has a property 'Button'. And the object has k,v for lets say width, height, and position. But in my other Object which defines available fields for 'Button' has width, height, position, color, and transition. What I am trying to do is, when I click on 'Button' label(see my demo) it shows me all the fields in my 'Controls' object and fills in all the values from my other Object which contains the values. I can then add values into the inputs that are empty and it will save them back to my Object.
Here is my Demo(click on the labels to see the form inputs): http://jsfiddle.net/bGxFC/6/

Here is my code:

```
    var controls = {
    "Controls": [{
        "Button":[{"Transition": "","BackgroundImage": "","Position": "","Width": "","Height": ""}],

        "Image":[{"BackgroundImage": "","Position": "","Width": "","Height": "", "Type": ""}],

        "Label":[{"Position": "","Width": "","Height": "","Text": "","FontSize":"","Color": "", "FontType": ""}]
    }]
};


var str = 'View\n{\n    Image\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Image.gif;\n        Position: 0, 0;\n        Width: 320;\n        Height: 480;\n    }\n\n    Button\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Button.gif;\n        Transition: View2;\n        Position: 49, 80;\n        Width: 216;\n        Height: 71;\n    }\n\n    Button\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;\n        Position: 65, 217;\n        Width: 188;\n        Height: 134;\n    }\n\n    Label\n    {\n        Position: 106, 91;\n        Width: 96;\n        Height: 34;\n        Text: "Button";\n        FontSize: 32;\n        Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;\n    }\n    \n\n}';

str = str.replace(/(\w+)\s*\{/g, "$1:{"); // add in colon after each named object
str = str.replace(/\}(\s*\w)/g, "},$1"); // add comma before each new named object
str = str.replace(/;/g, ","); // swap out semicolons with commas
str = str.replace(/,(\s+\})/g, "$1"); // get rid of trailing commas
str = str.replace(/([\d\.]+(, [\d\.]+)+)/g, "[$1]"); // create number arrays
str = str.replace(/"/g, ""); // get rid of all double quotes
str = str.replace(/:\s+([^\[\d\{][^,]+)/g, ':"$1"'); // create strings
$("#parseList").html(str);

var objStr;
eval("objStr={" + str + "};");
//End Parse String

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $objectList = $('<div id="main" />').appendTo($('#main'));
    $.each(objStr.View, function(k, v) {
        $('<div/>').append(k).appendTo($objectList).on('click', function(){
            var $wrapper = $('#form .wrapper').empty();
            if(typeof v === 'string') {
                $('<div class="item" />').append('<span class="key">' + k + '</span>' + '<input value="' + v + '"/>').appendTo($wrapper);
            }
            else {//object
                $('<h3 class="formHeading" />').append(k).appendTo($wrapper);
                $.each(v, function(key, val) {
                    $('<div class="item" />').append('<span class="key">' + key + '</span>' + '<input value="' + val + '"/>').appendTo($wrapper);
                });
            }
            $("<button>Save</button>").appendTo($wrapper).on('click', function() {
                if(typeof v === 'string') {
                    v = $(this).closest(".wrapper").find("input").val();
                }
                else {//object
                    $(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".item").each(function(i, div) {
                        var $div = $(div),
                            key = $div.find(".key").text(),
                            val = $div.find("input").val();
                        v[key] = val;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

How would I solve this problem?

Comment: can merge 2 objects with `$.extend`... not clear which needs to be master

Comment: @charlietfl The Primary Object is 'objStr' the 'controls' Object is only to define the available form inputs. Everything gets saved to 'objStr'.

Comment: so can you be specific about combining the 2 then? Not totally clear what needs to happen here.

Comment: @charlietfl Sure... I am going to use one specific use case. First please go to my Demo http://jsfiddle.net/bGxFC/6/ and click on the label "Button". You will see a few input come up for "BackgroundImage", "Position", "Width", and "Height". I can currently change these values, hit save and they are saved to the Object. Now look at the first 'var controls' in my JS(at the top). You can see that "Button" not only has the 4 fields mentioned above, but it also has "Transition". What needs to happen is when I click "Button" label on my html, it will bring up all the fields listed in ..cont

Comment: 'controls' object and populate the inputs with the values that match. In this case "BackgroundImage", "Position", "Width", and "Height"...while "Transition" will be blank. When I type in something into the "Transition" input and hit save, it will be stored in the same Object that the other values are in.

Comment: OK...getting closer but when you refer to `same object` or `saved to the Object` is a bit hard to follow. In this fiddle there are 2 specifically named objects: http://jsfiddle.net/bGxFC/7/ Rference by object name would help. http://jsfiddle.net/bGxFC/7/

Comment: Also `Controls` has arrays for elements. Need to explain why and how they come into play. If you are storing multple same type...will need a way to identify them such as every element in form needs a unique ID or something. Assume you will store these in DB and would need the same there

Comment: if you are designing data structure...and have flexibility in it's design...likely easier ways to make this work more efficiently. But not really clear on the higher level use of all this

Comment: @charlietfl 'objStr' holds values for elements and 'controls' is just a template for available fields for the elements'. Thats why all the values in 'controls' are empty' they will never store anything. But 'objStr can have multiple "Buttons" all with their own values. In my example of "Button" if I enter a value into the "Transition" input, it would add that value to objStr along with the "Width", "Height", Position", etc that were already there.

Comment: I can be flexible on the 'controls' object, but not on the 'objStr' as it needs to match another system we have.

Comment: @charlietfl fyi the fiddle is giving error 500 bad gateway

Comment: controls just needs simple array of attributes for each type of element then...  500 must man jsfiddle site having issues. Can't get any fiddles open right now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21883/discussion-between-charlietfl-and-rob)

Comment: you have a big problem with structure of `objStr` since it can only have one of any type, like `Button,Image etc`. Without resolving that you will be spinning your wheeels

Comment: @charlietfl I have actually solved that via regex by appending an incremented number to the element ie. Button turns into 'Button_1". If we can just work with my demo, I should be able to get it to work in my solution by stripping it when mapping it and then adding it back when saving.

Comment: appended `_1` doesn't show up in fiddle that prints the object: http://jsfiddle.net/bGxFC/7/

Comment: should consider mapping all this out in a workflow first...before worrying about parsing objects. WOrkflow is deinfitely not well established enough to follow. Not sure what end game is but this data structure is not extremely friendlly yet. Flow should include how to match html to object

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show you the incrementing. http://jsfiddle.net/bGxFC/8/ it also shows you two "Buttons". If you look at "Button_1" you will see that it has a field called "Transition" but "Button_2" does not. What im trying to accomplish is having "Button_2" still have a "Transition" input because its defined in "controls" object. Hopefully this is more clear now

Comment: @charlietfl also both "Button_1" and "Button_2" are defined as "Buttons" in the "controls" object. I will assume that in order to map them will will need to drop the numbering to make a match. Here is the code i used for that. '.replace(/Text:[\s]*([^;}\r\n]+)/ig, 'Text:  "$1"')'

Comment: OK..so narrow down exactly what you need then...how to save updates back to the object? Also why all the regex... can't you add a property like `type` that matches controls?

Comment: @charlietfl actually YES. I can add a 'Type' property and use that to match. I have updated the demo to reflect that. Could you assist with how I would map that? http://jsfiddle.net/bGxFC/9/

Comment: map to do what...still haven't gotten to the exact mapping issue is. WOuld be a lot simpler working with readable object that your string parser creates and understanding exactly what needs to happen

Comment: @charlietfl regarding other comments. all the regex is used to manipulate a horrible string into a valid object. and The same flow that is currently on the demo is how I want it to work. The only difference being that the input fields are being generated by 'controls' and 'objStr' is populating them.. The key here is that upon saving the inputs, any inputs that were filled out and not already in 'objStr' will be added to it.

Comment: @charlietfl for mapping, the only way I can explain it is in the demo... Click on "Button_1" it has values for all 6(added one 'Type'http://jsfiddle.net/bGxFC/10/) properties available in 'controls.Button', but if you click on "Button_2" it only has values for 4 of the properties and it doesnt have the ability to add the fifth property("Transition"). Thats what im trying to fix. I need to be able to add those values to incomplete elements. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need the input elements in html to contain the object keys they associate too.

Something like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h3 class="formHeading" data-item="Button_2">Button_2</h3>

<div class="item"><span class="key">Type</span><input value="Button" data-property="Type"></div>
<div class="item"><span class="key">BackgroundImage</span><input value="Button2.gif"  data-property="BackgroundImage"></div>
<div class="item"><span class="key">Position</span><input value="65,217"></div><button class="save">Save</button>

</div>
```

JS

```
$('button.save').click(function(){
    var $form=$(this).closest( '.wrapper'), itemName=$form.find('.formHeading').data('item')
   var objectItem= storedObject[ itemName ];

   $('.item').each(function(){
        var $input=$(this).find(':input');
        objectItem[ $input.data('property')]= $input.val();
   })  

})
```

If you can get rid of all of the string parser and use a proper javascript object in a demo, and add these html modifications I will be happy to help debug from there

Comment: I am not sure this will work for me because in production I have dozens of elements(i.e Buttons, Labels, Images, etc) which is why I have the form being generated dynamically. Please correct me if im wrong but using tis I will have to have an html form created for every element

Comment: no... you can create the html on the fly from the object. When you create the html as you are doing now just add the concepts I gave you. You have to be able to match  the html fields back to the object

Comment: Im sorry, im having trouble understanding. Is it possible for you to show me in my demo?

Comment: no....this is starting to become managing a whole app. In the html parsing code you have now...add the extra html properties I showed. Inspect your current html in browser console....that's where I copied it from to add the new `data-` attributes

Comment: I tried adding them in several different ways and I just cant figure out where it fits into my code. If I could see how one field being created from `controls` and populated using `objStr` within my code example I can most definitely take it form there. I am just having trouble wrapping my head around mapping these two objects dynamically with forms and saving back to `objStr`